# Open browser keyword is not launching browser aftwr i upgrade selenium from 4.9.0 to 4.10

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

When I upgraded to `selenium 4.10` , open browser keyword is unable to open chrome browser .
Seeing `init()` got an unexpected keyword argument `service_log_path`
I can see some results for selenium python
But I don't see any result for robot framework.
Can anyone suggest how to launch the browser in robot framework without downgrading `selenium` from 4.10 to 4.9

My code is:

```
Open Browser url="https://ww.google.com"
browser="chrome"
executable_path="C:\driver\chromedriver.exe"
```

Works in `selenium 4.9` and throws error in `selenium 4.10`

I have tried for 2 days and experiencing same error

Comment: It sounds like you hit this issue: https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/1836